# Shopify product price divided by 10

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I have previously made a financing calculator, so you can see the price if you pay over 10 months. An update has arrived in Shopify, which blocks my scripts.

```
monthly payment <span class="grafikr-finans-price-10">{{ product.price | divided_by: 10 | money }}</span></p>

$('.grafikr-finans-price-10').text(((price.replace('.','')/10).toFixed(1) + '0 kr.').replace('.',','))
```

Anyone know how to fix the problem? 
You can se the problem here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZTu0.jpg

You can see the full script here:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setprice() {
  
       var price = $('#price-field').text().replace(',00 DKK','')
    for (i = 0; i < $('.grafikr-finans-price').length; i++) {
     $('.grafikr-finans-price').text(price + ' kr.')
    }
     $('.grafikr-finans-price-10').text(((price.replace('.','')/10).toFixed(1) + '0 kr.').replace('.',','))
  }
  
  setprice()
  
  $('.sod_option').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      setprice()
    }, 500)
  
  }); 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`price.replace` is going to give you a string, which cannot be divided (hence `NaN`).

Try this:

```
var price = parseInt($('#price-field').text().replace(',00 DKK',''))
// snipped...
$('.grafikr-finans-price-10').text(price/10).toFixed(1)
```

Comment: This to not seems to work. It must be taken into account that it is a variant product that changes the price according to one's choice. https://imgur.com/a/GsIjdNm

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link to the page?  I'd like to do a bit of testing before updating my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the URL: https://www.sengefabriksudsalg.dk/collections/kontinental-senge/products/nordkap-kontinental-pocket-180x200-cm I have postet the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This work :-)

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setprice() {
  
    var price = $('#price-field').text().replace(',00 DKK','')
    for (i = 0; i < $('.grafikr-finans-price').length; i++) {
     $('.grafikr-finans-price').text(price)
    }
    $('.grafikr-finans-price-10').html(
      ((parseInt(price.replace('.','')) / 20).toFixed(1) + '0 kr.').replace('.',',')
    );
  }
  
  setprice()
  
  $('.sod_option').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      setprice()
    }, 500)
  
  }); 
 
});
</script>
```